# Prevent Elasticsearch to crash on aws micro t2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I've been using Elasticsearch for the last couple of weeks and it works great integrated with symfony.

However, I've noticed that the server is crashing every 2-3 days. Our site is really small so for the next 3-6 months, we plan on using one node.

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND 
26261 elastic+  20   0 1323504 781936  22576 S  0.3 76.9   0:17.71 java

Our AWS instance is t2-micro and has 1GB of memory.

And I have assigned on elasticsearch configuration file.

HEAP_SIZE: 512m
number_of_shards: 5 (I've just moved to 1)
number_of_replicas: 1 (I've just moved to 0)

Our Index size is really small, around 97kb, we're storing 63 products.
But on average we will around 200.

So the questions that I have is:

1- Is there a recommeded configuration for one node in a really small server

2- Is there a way to diagnose the crash, the logs in Trace mode, didn't give me any hints of what went wrong.

3- Is there a way to automatically restart Elasticsearch when it crashes, like maybe with supervisor.

[EDITED]

```
{"primaries":
{
 "docs":{"count":61,"deleted":2},
 "store":   {"size_in_bytes":62212,"throttle_time_in_millis":0},
 "indexing":{"index_total":0,"index_time_in_millis":0,"index_current":0,"delete_total":0,"delete_time_in_millis":0,"delete_current":0,"noop_update_total":0,"is_throttled":false,"throttle_time_in_millis":0},
 "get":{"total":0,"time_in_millis":0,"exists_total":0,"exists_time_in_millis":0,"missing_total":0,"missing_time_in_millis":0,"current":0}
```

Comment: How many documents you have in the index? what kind of queries are executed on the index? do you use aggregations?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question with the stats you asked. I don't use aggregation, only simple keywords queries.